# two string date compare with simple dateformat like EE,MMM dd yyyy

Tags: android, datetime, compare, simpledateformat

i need to compare two string  dates with SimpleDateformat like EE,MMM dd yyyy
but when i compare it it will validate only the first value "EE" only other month,date and year not validating if anyone know this problem solution please help me to solve and thanks in advance to all

Comment: You wanna count days between two dates ?

Comment: No i need to know greater or equal

Comment: obviously `"March" > "April"` ... (if you comparing strings) ... dates in such format are nor comparable as strings

Comment: i need to display the date in this format  EE,MMM dd yyyy then how to compare the date with this format, if this date will convert to timestamp

Answer (score 1):

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"/*or whatever your format is*/, Locale.US);
        try {
            Date actualDate = format.parse(actualDate);
            Date dateToCompare = format.parse(dateToCompare);

           if (actualDate.after(dateToCompare) || actualDate.before(dateToCompare)) {
                // Toast.makeText(context,""+actualDate.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Compare it with date format and then use the String result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  public static void main( String[] args )
{
    try{

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy");

        Date date1 = sdf.parse("date1 example"); 
        Date date2 = sdf.parse("date2 example");

        System.out.println(sdf.format(date1));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date2));

        if(date1.compareTo(date2)>0){
            System.out.println("Date1 is > Date2");
        }else if(date1.compareTo(date2)<0){
            System.out.println("Date1 is <Date2");
        }else if(date1.compareTo(date2)==0){
            System.out.println("Date1 is = to Date2");
        }else{
            System.out.println("!!!");
        }

    }catch(ParseException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Update**

If you wanna use `Calendar` :

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    try{

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy");
        Date date1 = sdf.parse("date1 example");
        Date date2 = sdf.parse("date2 example");

        System.out.println(sdf.format(date1));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date2));

        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime(date1);
        cal2.setTime(date2);

        if(cal1.after(cal2)){
            System.out.println("Date1 is > Date2");
        }

        if(cal1.before(cal2)){
            System.out.println("Date1 is < Date2");
        }

        if(cal1.equals(cal2)){
            System.out.println("Date1 is = Date2");
        }

    }catch(ParseException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you wanna add days to your date do the following :

```
String date = "your date";  // your date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);  // 3 days to add
date= sdf.format(c.getTime());  // put the new date in date variable
```

Hope it helps

Comment: in this format can i increase one  day by click action

Comment: Yes but you have to use `Calendar` api to add one day like that `add(Calendar.DATE, 1);`